# Как использовать сессии в Django?

Tags: python, django, cookie, сессия

Допустим, есть простой сайт вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если ввести название города в форму, можно получить информацию о погоде в этом городе.
Я хочу чтобы у каждого пользователя был свой список городов, который где-то сохранялся.
Никакой авторизации на сайте нет.
Что для этого лучше использовать cookie или session?
Где лучше в данном случае сохранять данные?
Если можно, краткий пример реализации этого в Django?

Answer (score 0):

Сессии. Django использует сессии через куки. В куках хранится ключ сессии, по которому делается выборка данных на стороне сервера

[Пример использования](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/#examples)